# Weird reactivity issue with arrays in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to debug a rather weird problem I've run into with a Vue.js application. Unfortunately it's way too complex to be able to isolate some code showing the problem, so I'm hoping that a clear description might be enough to enable people to give me some pointers as to where to look.

I have a component called ItemSelector, which has a 'targetList' prop of type Array. On a form, I use this component 3 times, passing a different array for each instance. Each array consists of sale item objects, and the ItemSelector component displays these items and allows the user to add, edit and delete them. All works just fine, except for one thing. The objects contain a property called 'subtotal'. If in one instance of my ItemSelector component I edit one of the item objects and clear the value of the 'subtotal' property, the item with the same index in the other instances of ItemSelector also has the 'subtotal' property cleared! That is, if I edit the second item in one of the ItemSelector instances, clearing the subtotal property, the second item, if present, in the other ItemSelector instances is also cleared. However, if I instead change the value to a different number, this has no effect on other instances of the component. It's only clearing the value which does it.

Does this make any sense at all to anyone? I cannot see how a change in one array could affect other arrays at all.

Comment: Maybe you have subtotal property connected with some `v-model` which change it on all, sorry but without code we can't help more

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that mean any change to subtotal would equally affect others, not just clearing it? I appreciate that without code it is difficult to get a good insight into the problem.

Comment: You can try debug it in VueDevtools. Like i said without code I can't help you.